# Running bash script in PHP after uploading a document

Tags: php, bash

I need some guidance for this project I am working on.
I have a script where it processes data and I want to use it on a server.

How can I integrate the command to run my script.sh located at ProcessedData/ please?

Thank you

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));

  $extensions= array("log");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a log file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152){
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"ProcessedData/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
   }
exec(parsing.sh);
?>
```

```
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="file" />
     <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

Here extract of my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -w BLABLABLA ProcessedData/ant_traps.log > result.csv
```

Comment: Is `parsing.sh` a string? That isn't valid syntax as is... `exec(parsing.sh);` Also, to help test your code we want to see the return value of `exec`... `$retval = exec($scriptName)`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec(scriptName)` to execute any script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I tried this but nothing is happening and so far I don't have any error message.

Comment: Answer is a little brief. You could improve this answer by talking about escaping shell arguments. for example.

Comment: I don't see any `exec` calls in your code... Can we see that code since we are talking about it?

Comment: @Mohamed as long as your directory is being accessed correctly (give the correct location for the script, try using the absolute path) this must work.

Comment: @electric.Kariim I have edited my code, but still nothing is happening my script is located same as my php file, and I have a folder called `ProcessedData` where my file is uploaded.  Is there anything wrong on my edit please ?

Comment: @electric.Kariim I found the solution !!

Comment: @Mohamed so `exec` worked for you? If so please upvote or mark answered ;)

Comment: @electric.Kariim I have used `shell_exec` to be more specific

Answer (score -1):

Here the solution

```
<?php
   if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));

  $extensions= array("log");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
 $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a log file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152){
 $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"ProcessedData/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
     }
       }
echo shell_exec('sh parsing.sh');
?>
```

Comment: Yes, calling execution from shell work like... a shell... `./`

Comment: @ficuscr, is there other alternative?

Comment: Let's put it another way, if it doesn't work when you type it in the command line / prompt, it won't work in `exec` either. So yeah, obviously `sh script.sh` or `./script.sh`. Has little to do with PHP or anything you initially asked. I'd close this whole thing as it is not likely to help others.

Comment: @ficuscr I got your point, what would you suggest in PHP please?

Comment: I have nothing else to add other than beware of [Command Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection).